# Using a singleton in my app. Am i implementing it correctly?

Tags: typescript, game-engine, component-based

So I have a class called app. It is just a class that controls all the other classes inside of it. Mid development we discussed to make this app class a singleton. This makes clear to other developers that there should only be one App. This sounds logical and is the correct way to use a singleton. The only questions arises that if you use this singleton to access its properties and make them accessible for others. Are you then using a singleton "incorrectly"? I know you should not use singleton "because it's convenient". But is this the case here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you use this singleton to access its properties and make them accessible for others, are you then using a singleton "incorrectly"?

Short answer: No

Long answer: It depends

Comment: I reckon that the long answer is too long to answer in a post. Is there anywhere I can do some research to understand it?

Comment: @jesseystend https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/singleton-design-pattern-pros-and-cons-e10f98e23d63/

Comment: Thanks @MedetTleukabiluly, I read the article and it helped me understand singletons a little more.